# How to create a condition clause using a current computer time

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL View which contains a column with dates of the '2012-06-21 19:44:50.543' format. I need to entre the condition to show only lines with dates starting from the beginning of the previous month. This procedure requires to use the current (inbuilt) time. Also I need such a View to be updated automatically each month. How can I do that?

Comment: You have more than one question here. Please modify the question for the first part, and post the second part as a separate question, if the answer below does not satisfy your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get dates starting from the previous month based on current system time, you will use [`DATEADD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [`GETDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx).

> `DATEADD` returns a specified *date* with the specified *number* interval
>   (signed integer) added to a specified *datepart* of that date.

```
    DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

> `GETDATE` returns the current database system timestamp as a **datetime** value without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running.

```
    GETDATE ( )
```

To calculate the dates that match from the start of last month (remember, this is an example and may need modification with your code):

```
SELECT [col1], [col2], [dt] FROM [table]
WHERE [dt] >= convert(varchar,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,
              DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,
              getdate()),0)),101)
```

Please do some reading about [`DATEDIFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) as well, and [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to understand how the formatting represented by `101` works. You may prefer `121` instead.

*(Additional source: Terry Apodaca’s article,
“SQL Dates – First, Current, Last Day of Month”, which moved

from <sup>[this old address](http://www.terryapodaca.com/2008/01/28/sql-dates-first-current-last-day-of-month)</sup>
to http://v1.terryapodaca.com/2008/01/28/sql-dates-first-current-last-day-of-month
(or you can read an archived copy at [the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120815190947/http://www.terryapodaca.com/2008/01/28/sql-dates-first-current-last-day-of-month)).)*